# gitlab4j - create a commit to branch from Java

Tags: java, git, gitlab-api

I am using gitlab4j API to access my GitLab Repository.
I want to commit a text file from my local system to specific branch.
How do I achieve this via gitlab4j API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see in the documentation, there is a [Commit API](https://github.com/gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api#commitsapi) that you can use to manage commits.

The Commit API has a method to [create](https://github.com/gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gitlab4j/api/CommitsApi.java#L743) a commit where you can specify the branch name, commit message and other details.